# Create a list of strings of a specific collection from Firebase database in Android Studio/Flutter

Tags: android, list, flutter

I need to create a scollable screen with some fixed parameters, and other parameters taken from a list.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

MORNING, AFTERNOON, EVENING & DO ANYTIME are fixed; inside each on them there is a list of habit made with a ListView.builder.

For now I have a ListView with the fixed ones and, inside, other ListView.builders.
The problem is that I can't scroll the page when I touch the lists of habits; I think I know the problem, flutter recognize as scrollable only the first ListView, but I don't not how to solve it.

I need the whole block (FIXED + lists) to be scrolled.

Suggestions?

Comment: Could someone provide a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'fixed' my problem by setting the inner listView.builders with physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics().

Answer (score 1):

You need [Slivers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers)

Check out [“Slivers, Demystified” by Emily Fortuna](https://link.medium.com/yh2kSBB221)

You might also find [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) useful as it's **behavior** property can control whether the behaviour is defered to the child view.